# Magene HR monitor, Avg 175 max 212?

Tags: bike-computer, heart-rate

[image: Heart Rate average 175bpm max 212bpm]

I just bought a Magene C406 pro and it measured what I show in the image. Does that makes sense? It was a strenuous ride, but everything felt in order, sustained, and the whole ride lasted 20 minutes (in which I seemingly averaged 175bpm).

Is this measurement OK, or is the Magene just bad quality?

Comment: Heart rates are individual but just for reference: In my 30s as a runner, doing hill reps and intervals, I think I hardly every did 175 as max HR, so that's a bit high for a 20-minute effort but not totally off the grid not knowing anything about your age and physique - did you clean the strap out of the box? BTW.: I think this is off-topic for Bicycles SE.

Comment: Hi @DoNuT , good to know. I saw the same question, just with different data, here: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/77354/false-hrm-results . So I thought it would count as On-topic.

Comment: My Magene most often woked well, but in many HR monitors you may get issues when you intermittently get 180 instead 120 or similar. Can you try to compare it with the HR measured with a finger on your vein and a stopwatch?

Comment: Fair enough, I'll try to put together an answer.

Comment: FWIW, I have measured similar and higher heart rates with several different heart rate monitors. Going hard without warming up first is a great way to get unusually high heart rates.

Comment: @ojs The fact that it starts out from 100-ish HR and then climbs is an indicator that it is not a total garbage reading. When readings are off, they are usually off right out of the gates, at least from my experience. And you then often get jumps back to normal values, like averaging 150-160 at moderate pace and the straight down 20 bpm at the blink of an eye. The above looks like a hard effort from the start and all-out towards the end. That being said, my head would explode at 200+ bpm^^

Comment: @DoNuT we may have discussed this before, but different people sometimes have really different experiences. Its really nice that your maximum heart rate is below 175, but it does not apply to everyone.

Comment: @ojs Fair point, I seem to be some kind of tractor in that regard but shouldn't make assumptions for others based on that. I've seen your (personal) answer on the related question, so it might be legit, but I'd still say people hitting 200+ heartrates on intense workouts are rare (scrolling lots of Strava) - and how do you know it is a legit reading and the OPs true baseline? I'd try to troubleshoot potential causes of error and to test the monitor against a secondary source, maybe even at the doctor's office just to see if it picks up the resting heart rate reliably for a start...

Comment: @DoNuT I'm not claiming that it's a correct measurement, but I don't see any obvious signs why it would not be. The heart rates are high but not impossible, and I don't see huge jumps or totally flat regions that are the usual signs of false readings.

Answer (score 3):

It is hard to tell without knowing your physical condition/training status (and the actual workout done) but not totally unrealistic for a human being. Seems a bit high, depending on what you did as exercise...

I'm pretty sure I never hit more than 175 bpm as maximum HR in 10+ years of sports with HRM belts. That doesn't apply to any other person since heart rates are an individual thing, but anyway, as suggested in [False hrm results](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/77354/false-hrm-results), I'd try to check the following points:

- Does it have good contact to your chest in all phases of your breathing, a good indicator is when it neither limits your chest movement but also doesn't require adjustment all the time - the latter is probably more an issue with running than cycling, though. Body hair might also impair readings...
- Try to clean the strap with soap and water
- Most of these sensors need some lubrication on the contact patch, usually sweat will do the job, I just lick it before fitting the strap
- Try replacing the battery, some old Garmins gave me weird readings when batteries were dying
- Are you riding with open jersey? I once had an old sensor that showed weird readings when I was going fast (mostly on descents) with open jersey - turned out that the readings went nuts due to wind exposure and the sweat layer vanishing - I only had that with a 2010s Garmin sensor, newer ones didn't show that behavior.

If the readings turn out to be consistent, I would suggest to verify against a secondary source and see if it matches up - I'm not saying it has to be a condition and you have to take a ECG under load but if you have no experience with your heart rate and just started (structured) training, there is no harm in consulting your doctor, there's no harm in knowing how your body behaves and knowing that you actually are a "high-pulser". In structured training, you should know and trust your [zones](https://support.polar.com/en/what-are-heart-rate-zones).

Also, as Weiwen mentioned: We don't know what the background of above's workout was, but from experience with training apps like Zwift, you hardly ever go into a hard effort without warm-up to avoid injury. Assuming your true max. heart rate is 210-215, you went into a 15+ minute zone 3 effort with a little zone 4-5 in the end. When you do this on a typical short Zwift workout, there's at least 5 minute warmup before you go through any hard blocks.

Answer (score 3):

One estimate of the *average* max HR for a given age is 220-age. This is *not* your own max HR, it’s the *average* max HR, and there are slightly better formulae than 220-age, but it is a start. And we can note that if your HR on this ride topped out at 212, your actual max HR is probably higher. An average of 175 is also seemingly high. So those values seem a bit unlikely. But you could just have a high heart rate!

However, as already said, heart rates are a very individual thing. I assume this is your first HRM, so you have no baseline. One thing you can do is warm up, take your pulse manually, then maybe do an interval and take your pulse again. Compare it to the HRM readings. Or borrow a friend’s smartwatch.

In general, I warm up for my threshold intervals. Actually, I always warm up, and most people should probably warm up rather than jump right into a hard 20 min effort. Perhaps you are young and you can get away with this for now, though! The ramp up from your starting HR seems fast, but my HR pretty quickly rises and stabilizes during my threshold or sweet spot intervals. [Here](https://intervals.icu/activities/10855335656) is one example session. Of course, and not to rub this in, but I was starting each interval from a warmed up state.

In general, HRMs are an established technology. Magene is a mainland China brand with some credibility. It’s likely that Magenes in general aren’t bad. It’s possible you got a dud, or something is interfering with the wireless signal. Wahoo's TICKRs have seemingly (from anecdotal reports from forums I'm on) had a number of duds. Polar is generally regarded well, but I heard one person report they had a dud from this company.

Answer (score 3):

It is not *that* difficult to check the readings of an HR monitor with an independent source. The start is really to put a finger on one of your big veins and feel the beats. Care must be taken not to overcount due to the beats in the fingers themselves but it usually works quite reasonably. It is not that difficult. It is not simple to do during the activity but it is simple enough to do it right after the end of a sprint or some other activity. Or even just for the rest heart rate. Then you just look at your watch and count the beats in 1/4 minute or in 1 minute or similar. You should get a very reasonable estimate of the true heart rate.

I do own a Magene heart strap but I haven't used it for several years because optical sensors on watches got much better than what they used to be. Id did have spurious results from time to time as I did with other optical sensors in other circumstances. It can happen.

If you can get a hold of such a watch, even if just borrow from a friend for a short time, that is also a good way to check the correctness of the strap. Even more accurate are the optical sensors in pulse oxymeters where you even see can see the curve on the display together with the current HR.

As mentioned in other answers, your indicated HR is high, but not impossibly so. But conspicuously high for sure.